# Adding and removing form validation to a nested form angular 8

Tags: angular, validation, reactive

I am trying to create a form that only has validation for two of the four fields, so trying to add and remove Validators for each field when the form is toggled. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I think im missing something very small.

You can download the repo here - https://github.com/1Guv/ths-reactive-forms

Here is my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.familyForm = this.parentForm.form;
    this.addFormControls();
  }

  toggle() {
    this.switch = !this.switch;
    this.addFormControls();
  }

  addFormControls() {
    // this.familyForm.clearValidators();
    if (!this.switch) {
      console.log('Father & Mother');
      this.familyForm.addControl('family', new FormGroup({
        fatherName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        motherName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        uncleName: new FormControl(''),
        auntieName: new FormControl('')
      }))
    } else {
      console.log('Uncle & Auntie');
      this.familyForm.addControl('family', new FormGroup({
        fatherName: new FormControl(''),
        motherName: new FormControl(''),
        uncleName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        auntieName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
      }))
    }
    this.familyForm.updateValueAndValidity();
    console.log('form controls', this.familyForm.controls);
  }
```

Here is my html:

```
<h6>Family Form Component</h6>
<div formGroupName="family">
  <h6 *ngIf="!switch">Father & Mother</h6>
  <div *ngIf="!switch" class="row">
    <br>
    <div class="col">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Father name</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="fatherName" class="form-control" placeholder="Father name">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Mother name</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Mother Name" formControlName="motherName" >
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h6 *ngIf="switch">Uncle & Auntie</h6>
    <div *ngIf="switch" class="row">
      <br>
      <div class="col">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Uncle name</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text" formControlName="uncleName" class="form-control" placeholder="Uncle name">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Auntie name</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Auntie Name" formControlName="auntieName" >
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>`enter code here`
</div>

<button type="button" class="m-4" mat-raised-button (click)="toggle()">Switch</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed in your toggle function and made one method which validate as per your requirement look at below code

```
toggle() {
    this.switch = !this.switch;
    this.setValidators();
 }
```

here is the setValidators method

```
    setValidators = () => {
    if (!this.switch) {
      console.log('Father & Mother');
      (<FormGroup>this.familyForm.controls['family']).controls['fatherName'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
      (<FormGroup>this.familyForm.controls['family']).controls['motherName'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
      (<FormGroup>this.familyForm.controls['family']).controls['uncleName'].setValidators(null);
      (<FormGroup>this.familyForm.controls['family']).controls['auntieName'].setValidators(null);
    } else {
      console.log('Uncle & Auntie');
      (<FormGroup>this.familyForm.controls['family']).controls['uncleName'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
      (<FormGroup>this.familyForm.controls['family']).controls['auntieName'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
      (<FormGroup>this.familyForm.controls['family']).controls['fatherName'].setValidators(null);
      (<FormGroup>this.familyForm.controls['family']).controls['motherName'].setValidators(null);
    }
}
```

hope this will help you,

let me know if you have any query

thanks

Comment: I tried your solution but got errors where controls are not defined, however I have fixed this issue with one line, I added ```this.familyForm.removeControl('family');``` in the addFormControls() function - thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
addFormControls() {
    this.familyForm.removeControl('family');
    if (!this.switch) {
      console.log('Father & Mother');
      this.familyForm.addControl('family', new FormGroup({
        fatherName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        motherName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        uncleName: new FormControl(''),
        auntieName: new FormControl('')
      }))
    } else {
      console.log('Uncle & Auntie');
      this.familyForm.addControl('family', new FormGroup({
        fatherName: new FormControl(''),
        motherName: new FormControl(''),
        uncleName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        auntieName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
      }))
    }
    this.familyForm.updateValueAndValidity();
    console.log('form controls', this.familyForm.controls);
  }
}
```